# Grails <g:link> rewriting links to match UrlMappings instead of controller/action

Tags: grails

Currently using grails 4.0.3.

I'm trying to generate a link to a controller action using a simple `<g:link>` tag:

```
<g:link controller="myController" action="myAction" params="[someParam:'myValue']">Link text</g:link>
```

In my UrlMappings file, I have this controller mapped to a common URL for external calls.  This mapping forces some parameters that I want forced when coming to this mapping:

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/service/someExposedUrl" {
      controller = "myController"
      action = "myAction"
      someParam = "defaultValue"
    }
  }
}
```

However, the link that gets written to the page in my application gets written using the UrlMapping definition.

```
http://serverUrl/service/someExposedUrl?someParam=<ignored>
```

instead of

```
http://serverUrl/myController/myAction?someParam=myValue
```

In this case, the parameters are ignored on the `/service` URL because they're hard-coded in the UrlMapping.

**Is there a way to force grails to link to the specified controller/action instead of the mapping?**

Comment: "Is there a way to force grails to link to the specified controller/action instead of the mapping?" - The behavior you are describing is intentional. Part of the point of using the `g:link` tag is to take advantage of the reverse url lookup so you don't have to hardcode URIs.  If you don't want reverse url mapping to take place, you could use something like `<g:link uri='myController/myAction'>`.

Answer (score 1):

Up front caveat: I have not tested this for this specific situation, though I have used these pieces individually.  Second caveat: I would not be remotely surprised to learn there's an even better way to do this...grails has a lot of options sometimes!

You should be able to create a named mapping in your UrlMappings, then reference that in your createLink.

UrlMappings:

```
name arbitraryName: "/myController/myAction" {
    controller = "myController"
    action = "myAction"
}
```

Link:

```
<g:link mapping="arbitraryName" params="[someParam:'myValue']">Link text</g:link>
```

Comment: This certainly works, leaving this open in case there are other suggestions before accepting this answer

Comment: @Trebla In the question you specifically said you did not want to use the mapping.

Comment: I understood this as "don't want to use the /service mapping" rather than "don't want to use a mapping at all".  Perhaps this was wrong.

Comment: While I would "like" to have a link directly to /myController/myAction, my main concern was avoiding using the existing "/someService/someExposedUrl" mapping because that adds a default parameter.  Daniel's suggestion of using a different mapping is sufficient, though I'd prefer not to have to define an additional mapping just for this case.  I'm open to other suggestions (e.g., forcing <g:link> to render the link to the controller instead of the /service mapping)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get what you need with a combination of Custom URL mapping and the exclude keyword in the original URLMappings.

Create MyControllerUrlMappings. This guide gives several examples of different ways of writing them out. I found it helpful.

```java
class MyControllerUrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
    
        // Url Mappings specific only to this controller
        
    }
}
```

https://guides.grails.org/grails_url_mappings/guide/index.html#_multiple_urlmappings_files

Your app will still be running the original UrlMappings file though. So you'll have the new custom Url mappings and the default ones. To fix that you can exclude your controller and it's methods in the original UrlMappings file.

```java
class UrlMappings {

    static excludes = [
            "/myController",
            "/myController/*"
    ]

    static mappings = {...}
    ...
```

Not as elegant as I'd like, but in a similar situation this is how I got it working.